# Retrieving specific elements from XML string using java

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing

Below is my code. I am able to parse xml, I am getting all the values if it in xml - For eg:- Part No i am getting all the values since it is in xml. While i am accessing MODEL, application terminates. How to check whether model tag is there or not and i want to check whether if tag is there value is empty or not.

```
PartNo[i].setText(el.getElementsByTagName("PART_NO").item(0).getTextContent());

if(el.getNodeName().contains("MODEL"))
{
    Model[i].setText(el.getElementsByTagName("MODEL").item(0).getTextContent());
}
```

The XML document looks like this:

```
<root>
  <DataSet>
    <PartNo>aaa</PartNo>
    <Model>bbbb</Model>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <PartNo>aaa</PartNo>
  </DataSet>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call `el.getNodeName().contains("MODEL"))` is checking whether the `String` node name of `el` contains `"MODEL"`, which is obviously wrong.

Reading between the lines, I think you want to check is there is a corresponding `Model` element for each `PartNo` element, which can be done like this with a DOM parser:

```
NodeList partNoElements = document.getElementsByTagName("PartNo");
for (int i = 0; i < partNoElements.getLength(); i++)
{
  Element partNoElement = partNoElements.item(i);

  PartNo[i].setText(partNoElement.getTextContent());

  Element modelElement = (Element)partNoElement.getNextSibling();
  if (modelElement != null && modelElement.getNodeName().equals("Model"))
  {
    Model[i].setText(modelElement.getTextContent());
  }
}
```

NOTE: this relies on the order of the elements always being as you've listed, which should be enforced by a schema if you're going to use this code.

Comment: Hi nick. Your code not working man. It is going into Dataset and printing all the values, but when i am getting nextsibling individually it is not working. and the getnodename().equals("Model") also not working.

Comment: Please someone answer quickly, i wanna finish the project.

Comment: The code I've listed isn't using the `DataSet` element, it's using the `PartNo` element then getting its *sibling*.  It's fragile, as I indicated in the answer, but it works

Comment: PS: requests to 'Please someone answer quickly' are unlikely to be well received on SO

Comment: how to check sibling is there of not.

Comment: if u can work with the particular xml and get the solution it would be fr8

Comment: The line `if (modelElement != null && modelElement.getNodeName().equals("Model"))` is checking the sibling is there and that it's a `Model` element

Comment: but if i give that na, application is stopped